# SweetAlert2 - after refresh href not working

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have this thing. After I refresh the page the script is stop working.
How do I need to do it to be working?

```
<a onclick="confirmation(event)" href="{{ url('trash/delete/'.$items->id) }}"> Delete</a>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
function confirmation(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href')
    
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'warning',
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: 'This action cannot be undone!',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, recall!'
        
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            window.location.href=url;
            
        }
    })
    
}

</script>
```

i have try this : location.reload(); in multilocation, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works for me using this library

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

can you try with this and see if it will work?

Comment: @GameDirect can you approve of this as an answer? I kind of need some reputation.